# Decreasing function and lower bound

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ a continuous positive, function and decreasing.
To prove that $ x\geqslant a $ is it sufficient to establish that $f(x)\leq f(a)$ ?

Comment: yes, I think it is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

No. It has to be *strictly* decreasing. This might seem nit-picky, but the standard definition of "decreasing" corresponds to the intuitive notion of "never increasing". As such, the function $f(x) = 5$ is, by definition, a decreasing function. As a less trivial example, the function
$$
g(x) = \cases{x^2 + 1 & if $x < 0$\\1 & if $x \geq 0$}
$$
is also decreasing.

If, however, the function is *strictly* decreasing, which more corresponds to what one might intuitively think the word "decreasing" means, namely that the function value actually gets smaller as the argument increases, then yes, that's enough. You don't even need the function to be continuous or positive.

Comment: The condition or the assumption that  f is a strictly decreasing function  is suffisant to deduce. Thus we have
If $f$ is a strictly decreasing function then   $f(x) < f(a) \Rightarrow  a < x$.

Comment: In the case when we have
 1) $f $ strictly decreasing
2) $f(x)\leq f(a) $,
Is there any additional condition  to deduce that $x\geq a$ ?

Comment: @user326064 No, that's enough to conclude.